# Server Error Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am de-structuring the image array from the product and I also used log to verify if its getting it correctly and it is. Still after doing so getting this error while passing the image to the urlFor function. client.js has the urlFor function.
Code:

**[slug].js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { client, urlFor } from "../../lib/client";
import {
  AiOutlineMinus,
  AiOutlinePlus,
  AiFillStar,
  AiOutlineStar,
} from "react-icons/ai";
import Product from "../../components/Product";

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
  const { image, name, details, price } = product;
  const { index, setIndex } = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product-detail-container">
      <div>
          <div className="image-container">
{            console.log(image)}
          <img src={urlFor(image && image[index])} className="product-detail-image" />
          </div>
          <div className="small-images-container">
            {image?.map((item, i) => (
              <img 
                key={i}
                src={urlFor(item)}
                className={i === index ? 'small-image selected-image' : 'small-image'}
                onMouseEnter={() => setIndex(i)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="product-detail-desc">
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <div className="reviews">
            <AiFillStar />
            <AiFillStar />
            <AiFillStar />
            <AiFillStar />
            <AiOutlineStar />
            <p>(20)</p>
          </div>
          <h4>Details:</h4>
          <p>{details}</p>
          <p className="price">₹{price}</p>
          <div className="quantity">
            <h3>Quantity:</h3>
            <p className="quantity-desc">
              <span className="minus" onClick="">
                <AiOutlineMinus />
              </span>
              <span className="num" onClick="">
                0
              </span>
              <span className="plus" onClick="">
                <AiOutlinePlus />
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
            <button type="button" className="add-to-cart" onClick="">
              Add to Cart
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="buy-now" onClick="">
              Buy Now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="maylike-products-wrapper">
        <h2>You may also like</h2>
        <div className="marquee">
          <div className="maylike-products-container track">
            {products.map((item) => (
              <Product key={item._id} product={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"] { 
        slug { current } }
    `;
  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: {
      slug: product.slug.current,
    },
  }));
  return { paths, fallback: "blocking" };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug }}) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
    const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]'
    
    const product = await client.fetch(query);
    const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);
  
    // console.log(product);
  
    return {
      props: { products, product }
    }
  }

export default ProductDetails;
```

**client.js**

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
    projectId: 'cbkf3z8c',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-03-10',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source)
```

The Error:

> Server Error
> Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
Call Stack
Object.urlForImage [as default]
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/@sanity/image-url/lib/node/urlForImage.js (47:15)
ImageUrlBuilder.url
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/@sanity/image-url/lib/node/builder.js (193:37)
ImageUrlBuilder.toString
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/@sanity/image-url/lib/node/builder.js (197:21)
createMarkupForProperty
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (1255:20)
createOpenTagMarkup
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3225:16)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.renderDOM
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4232:15)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3802:21)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.read
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3690:29)
Object.renderToString
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4298:27)
renderDocument
file:///C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/Code%20%F0%9F%A7%91%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%BB/ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (811:47)
```

I used console log to verify if its getting it correctly and it is. Still after doing so getting this error while passing the image to the urlFor function. client.js has the urlFor function.

Comment: log output: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{_key: 'b9575e136b81', _type: 'image', asset: {…}}
1
: 
{_key: 'cbf294485e6f', _type: 'image', asset: {…}}
2
: 
{_key: 'c3796e1d893d', _type: 'image', asset: {…}}
3
: 
{_key: 'de9f2516f5a1', _type: 'image', asset: {…}}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)

Comment: How are you getting the `source`? Am I understanding correctly that it should be a property of the `image` object? If so, is it present in the log you posted (once you fully expand it)?

Comment: `source` is the argument to the `urlFor()` function which in this case is the image itself. I am passing it to get the url for the image. the log for image expanded `0
: 
asset
: 
{_ref: 'image-e6d2e12006a2465551d4b1c4704d60151d0d1217-950x950-png', _type: 'reference'}
_key
: 
"b9575e136b81"
_type
: 
"image"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object`

Answer (score 0):

A stupid mistake but noteworthy. Instead of curly braces:

```
 const { index, setIndex } = useState(0);
```

Gotta use box braces

```
  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);
```